# Main method not found - Maven Project

Tags: java, selenium, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm currently trying to create my first maven project in VSCode, I have all the dependencies and extensions/plugins, however I'm getting a main method not found error even tho it's clearly declared.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class App{
public static void main(String[]args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxx\chromedriver.exe"
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
WebElement p =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='https://www.gooogle2.com/");
driver.quit();
}
}
```

I omitted some code due to the sake of time and not being able to copy/paste from my work laptop. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Show the actual code having the actual problem.

Comment: How do you create your project? 

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a space between your `main(String[] args){}`.
You're also missing a closing parentheses on line 7.
Try to run after fixing said problems, after which you should try

```bash
$ mvn clean
$ mvn compile
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.App
```

in the root directory of your project.

Replace `com.example` with the package your main class resides in.

Comment: Sorry for being rather new to Java and maven, 

- those errors were due to my laziness and not being able to copy/paste the code
- I got even more errors when trying to run those maven commands in the root directory

I don't know what you mean by replace com.example with the package my main class resides in. Could you explain? I see the path in the files are main\java\com\example & test\java\com\example but I'm not sure what you mean to do with this.